# Vim autoclose plugin and different keymap layouts

Tags: vim, auto-close

I find autoclose.vim very practical to have all brackets closed but encountered next problem.
The thing is i need to use second keymap in my work like following:

```
set keymap=russian-jcukenwin
```

This keymap with all others remaps these keys: "["->"х", "]"->"ъ", "'"->"э", "`"->"ё".
But when i insert autoclose.vim in my plugins i end up in situation where in russian-jcukenwin keymap i have no "х","ъ","э","ё" but "[","]","'","`" instead. I'm only starting my fun with vim and don't know its scripting language yet to find the solution in autoclose.vim by myself but find the problem very annoying.

So maybe someone knows a quick hack to avoid the remapping in autoclose.vim? Or maybe there is a way to auto turn off autoclose.vim in different keymap layout?

Answer (score 1):

You can run `:AutoCloseToggle` to disable/enable `autoclose.vim` plugin.

You can type <kbd>Ctrl-^</kbd>(insert mode) to disable/enable `keymap` option

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Yes Ctrl-^ is what i'm using to switch between layouts in insert mode. However :AutoCloseToggle really turns off the autoclose feature which autoinserts the closing brackets and in russian-jcukenwin keymap it turns closing brackets off but remap itself is not turned off. So i end up with same remapping problem but with no closing brackets this time.